# How do I add menu items within a .install file

Tags: features, distributions, aegir

I'm trying to build an intall profile that implements a number if features. I am running into some issues because although features allows me to require menus, it seems there is no way to also include the links (most of the link are simple aliases to add content or edit views). Is there a way to add menu items from within the install profile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow the example from the profiles/standard/standard.install file and use code like this inside your implementation of `hook_install()`:

```
// Create a Home link in the main menu.
$item = array(
  'link_title' => st('Home'),
  'link_path' => '<front>',
  'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
);
menu_link_save($item);
```

Comment: Thanks! what if the menu is hierarchical, for instance I have a menu the has an events link, and under the events link is an add events link

Comment: You can pass `plid` as the parent link ID in your `$item`, so save 'Events' first, then save `Add Events` with a `plid` of the first item's `mlid` (menu link id, it's returned from `menu_link_save()`)